# How to put buffers named with an asterisk at the end of ido's selection list?

Tags: ido, sorting

with `(ido-switch-buffer)`, when I type `stuff`, `"*magit: stuff*"` comes before `Stuff.txt`.

the sorting seems to be done by recency, rather than the buffer name. more generally, a custom sort function would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I use:

```lisp
(require 'dash)
(require 's)

(add-hook 'ido-make-buffer-list-hook 'my/ido-stars-to-end)
(defun my/ido-stars-to-end ()
  "Put \"*starred*\" buffers at the end of the ido candidates list."
  (ido-to-end (--filter (s-starts-with-p "*" it)
                        ido-temp-list)))
```

EDIT: as mentioned in a comment, the code above will put all "starred" buffers at the end of the list, even the currently selected one if its name contains an asterisk. A slightly modified version avoiding that effect would be:

```lisp
(require 'dash)
(require 's)

(add-hook 'ido-make-buffer-list-hook 'my/ido-stars-to-end)
(defun my/ido-stars-to-end ()
  "Put \"*starred*\" buffers at the end of the ido candidates list."
  (ido-to-end (--filter (and (s-starts-with-p "*" it)
                             (not (equal it (buffer-name))))
                        ido-temp-list)))
```

Comment: How do I make it ignore (not push to the end) current buffer (when current buffer is "starred")?

Comment: Ok, managed to make it by myself:
`(defun my/ido-stars-to-end ()
  (ido-to-end
   (-filter (lambda (it)
              (and
               (s-starts-with-p "*" it)
               (not (equal it (buffer-name)))
               )
              )
            ido-temp-list)))
(add-hook 'ido-make-buffer-list-hook 'my/ido-stars-to-end)`

the essential part is a new filter lambda: `(-filter (lambda (it) (and (s-starts-with-p "*" it) (not (equal it (buffer-name))))))`

Comment: thanks, I edited my post to account for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

If you want just for ido locally and not across tramp listings, then try this function that was [originally made](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) for buffers with @ in names and I modified for * in names:

```
(defun ido-sort-on-stars-to-end ()
    (message ido-current-directory)
    (setq ido-temp-list
        (sort ido-temp-list
            (lambda (a b)
              if (not (or (char-equal (string-to-char a) ?*) (char-equal (string-to-char b) ?*)))
            (time-less-p
             (sixth (file-attributes (concat ido-current-directory b))
                    (sixth (file-attributes (concat ido-current-directory a)))))
             nil)))
                  (ido-to-end
                   (delq nil (mapcar
                              (lambda (x) (and (string-match-p "^\\.." x) x))
                              ido-temp-list))))
```